# ADO .NET connection string doesn't work on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ado.net

I have a connection string in my web.config file like this

```
<add name="ModelDbContext" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DizlyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DizlyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DizlyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source={Server},1433;initial catalog=Dizlybeta;user id={id};Password={Password};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

but then I go to my hosted azure website and place this as connection

[image]

And then I replace the hidden security with

```
metadata=res://*/Models.DizlyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DizlyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DizlyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source={Server},1433;initial catalog=Dizlybeta;user id={id};Password={Password};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;
```

but it still doesn't work, can anyone help me with how to place the right connection string in the website configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Something to try:

Use a SqlClient connection string instead of an EntityClient connection string.

In that case, you'll probably need to pass the name of the connection string to the DbConext constructor, which you can do in one place like:

```
public MyDbContext : base("sqlClientConnectionStringName")
{
}
```

You might also need to ensure a SqlClient provider exists. Check [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj556606.aspx) for more.